# Can I make use of the food and utensils my ex-roommate left behind?

Tags: halal-haram, practical-islam

I had a roommate who moved out recently but left foodstuff and cooking utensils behind. Is it permissible for me to make use of the utensils and eat of the food? Because otherwise it would get spoilt and go to waste.
I have tried reaching her but she hasn't been responding and I'm sort of certain she won't be coming to get it back. What to do?

Comment: If she's left behind them and don't respond to get them back, it means these staffs are throw into trash. Then using them is like using trash and has nothing bad about that. If one day she want them back you can't give them and explain her.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think this question applies to this site. In any case, you should first try your hardest to get in contact with your roommate. If you cant, and there are food items, then you should eat the food items. There is no point in it going bad. An alternative would be to donate/cook it for the homeless in your area (be careful of laws and stipulations of doing this though).

As for the utensils, it depends on the relationship you had with your roommate. If the utensils were being shared before, then I'd imagine he left them for you to continue to use out of his own goodwill. If you had separate utensils, then you should have your own anyways, and you should neatly pack up his stuff in a box.

Like I mentioned, it greatly depends on your relationship with your roommate. If at any point he comes backs and demands his food (even a few weeks later), you can always give him a small gift card for the grocery store out of your own goodwill.

This is exactly what Islam teaches us. Be patient and be considerate that his property is indeed his property and you must take care in using it.